# Error a la hora de iniciar mi proyecto tomcat (Servlets)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

**Hola!**
Recién clone un repo que tenia en mi github (un proyecto que vengo desarrollando en java, tomcat).
A la hora de correrlo y estar en mi login form y darle click me sale esto:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instanciando clase de servlet [servlet.loginServlet]
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:670)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1786)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

causa raíz

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: servlet.loginServlet
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1329)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1141)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:670)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1786)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
```

No entiendo, mi codigo esta correcto, ya que esta repo lo hice ayer y lo ultimo que subí fue unas modificaciones pero en la estética de mi web.

¿Alguna solucion?

Pd: probe creando otro proyecto y al parecer son los package y clase servlets. Estan bien mapeados.

Para crear este proyecto use la IDE netbeans, pero para ejecutarlo y crearlo use IntelliJ, así que no creo que el IDE sea el problema, y recordar que probe con otro proyecto ahora si, creandolo desde IntelliJ y me sigue dando el mismo error.

Answer (score 0):

Solucione el error.
Y al parecer si tiene que ver algo la IDE.
Pero tambien fue version de mi plugin del war.

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Antes que nada les cuento que volvi a reinstalar netbeans, a lo que decidi tambien probar, a mi sorpresa en la consola de la IDE me arojaba un error del war, despues de un rato de estar toqueteando el proyecto di con el error, y fue la version de mi war (contaba con una version 2.0.0) a lo que decidi actualizarla y esta vez, con el mismo netbeans compilar el proyecto y dicho y hecho, funciono ahora.
Pude correrlo de manera satisfactoria en mi otro IDE.

Note que se me actualizo lo siguiente:

```
 <component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_21" default="true" project-jdk-name="17" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK" />
```

Y dejo claro un punto importante, en caso de que presenten un error similar al mio.

1. Revisar que version de JDK estan manejando.

En mi caso el primer factor a ver fue este, que mi jdk estaba con la version anterior con la que estaba manejando (justo ayer formatee mi equipo y contaba con esa, al dida de hoy me instale la jdk 21.

Eso es todo, espero poder ayudar con este comentario a las personas!